# Android Maps get Scroll Event

Tags: android, maps

i am currently developing an app with the Andoid Maps SDK.

Now i would like to get a notice if the user scrolls the map to load additional markers from a server based on the new map center.

I already searched for a function to register a listener but i didn´t find anything.

Is there any way to get informed about map center changes? I don´t want to implement a polling mechanism for that... :(

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in two ways:

**Touch listener.** Set the on touch listener for the map view. Every time the user lifts their finger (or moves, or touches down), you can reload.

```
mapView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // The user took their finger off the map, 
            // they probably just moved it to a new place.
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // The user is probably moving the map.
            break;
        }

        // Return false so that the map still moves.
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Override onLayout.** Every time the map moves, onLayout is called. If you extend the MapView class, you can override onLayout to catch these event. I set a timer in here to see whether the movement had stopped.

```
public class ExtendedMapView extends MapView {
    private static final long STOP_TIMER_DELAY = 1500; // 1.5 seconds
    private ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor mExecutor;
    private OnMoveListener mOnMoveListener;
    private Future mStoppedMovingFuture;

    /**
     * Creates a new extended map view.
     * Make sure to override the other constructors if you plan to use them.
     */
    public ExtendedMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mExecutor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
    }

    public interface OnMoveListener {
        /**
         * Notifies that the map has moved. 
         * If the map is moving, this will be called frequently, so don't spend 
         * too much time in this function. If the stopped variable is true, 
         * then the map has stopped moving. This may be useful if you want to
         * refresh the map when the map moves, but not with every little movement.
         * 
         * @param mapView the map that moved
         * @param center the new center of the map
         * @param stopped true if the map is no longer moving
         */
        public void onMove(MapView mapView, GeoPoint center, boolean stopped);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

        if (mOnMoveListener != null) {
            // Inform the listener that the map has moved.
            mOnMoveListener.onMove(this, getMapCenter(), false);

            // We also want to notify the listener when the map stops moving.
            // Every time the map moves, reset the timer. If the timer ever completes, 
            // then we know that the map has stopped moving.
            if (mStoppedMovingFuture != null) {
                mStoppedMovingFuture.cancel(false);
            }
            mStoppedMovingFuture = mExecutor.schedule(onMoveStop, STOP_TIMER_DELAY,
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is run when we have stopped moving the map. 
     */
    private Runnable onMoveStop = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (mOnMoveListener != null) {
                mOnMoveListener.onMove(ExtendedMapView.this, getMapCenter(), true);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

You can use the timer in the touch listener method as well. This was just an example. I hope this helps!

Comment: wasted so much time on this.None of the method works. downvote is neccessary.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following blog post (comes with Github code):
http://bricolsoftconsulting.com/extending-mapview-to-add-a-change-event/

Comment: It does work -- for many people -- as you can see from the comments on that page. It may not work for you, depending on your Android OS and/or device. But leaving a vague comment and giving me a downvote is not going to help anyone. How about engaging in a constructive conversation here and letting us know what device and what version of Android you are using?

Comment: I'm using Galaxy Nexus on 4.1 and Galaxy Note 10.1 on 4.0, the component rarely throws change event at all. It takes a lot of time and scrolling until it throws first change event, then it stops working again. It is much more reliable to handle touch event listener from the standard MapView. So it doesn't work, my users are not bound to one device the author was testing on.

Comment: Just tested the code again on a Nexus S running 4.0.3 and on a Nexus 4 running 4.2.1. The code works as intended on both: if you tap the map you get a toast saying 'Map Tap', if you zoom in/out you get a toast saying 'Map Zoom' and if you pan the map you get a toast saying 'Map Pan'. This happens reliably, every time it should. Not sure why it would not be working on Galaxy Nexus / Galaxy Note.