# Help needed with multiple itemized overlays on a mapview

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay

I am looking for some help....

Firstly I have a database server side with a numerous amount of locations(longs +lats)

Now there are upto a 1000 for one city alone. At the moment, my android device all the information at once. I then create 1000 itemized overlays and add them to the map view.
This in turn makes my emulator and phone run slow.

One idea I had was to zoom in on a location and then download and place a subset of the overlays on the map view.
Trouble I have with this
1. When I scroll on the map I don't know what event to register a listener to.
2. When the user zooms out I will still create the large number of itemised overlays.

My question to you guys is,

How could I overcome these problems? Or how would you go about doing this?

The solution Would be something similar to how google maps works. U c a not so detailed map when u zoom out, but when u zoom in it shows you a detailed map that reloads as you move around

Answer (score 1):

> I then create 1000 itemized overlays and add them to the map view.

Ummmm... please tell me that this is a typo, and you meant "1000 `OverlayItems`", not "1000 `ItemizedOverlays`".

1000 `OverlayItems` might be bad enough -- `ItemizedOverlay` isn't really designed for that many points.

> When I scroll on the map I don't know what event to register a listener to.

I don't think there is a straightforward solution here. I think others have kinda reverse-engineered the touch events and are listening on those. See [Android Maps get Scroll Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672655/android-maps-get-scroll-event) for more.

> When the user zooms out I will still create the large number of itemised overlays.

Use a prioritization scheme. What you see with Google Maps is that only the top N items are shown, where "top" is based on some sort of priority mechanism.

Comment: .. that was a typo 
 
It's a 1000 Overlays added to a list within an itemised overlay ... i think at the moment, if the zoom level is high i will just show an overlay with a number of the locations in a specific region